# How to resolve this error 'unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str''' with hexadecimal number?

Tags: python

Let's suppose that I have:

```
Plaintext= '53be6f50bf838a42b1ffda01ff64c162'
key= '000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f'
```

In my code, I have a function called sbox which I must use in  this line `sbox[ Plaintext[0] ^ Key[0]]` but it gives me this error :

```
    tempSbox = (sbox[Plaintext[0] ^ Key[0]])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'
```

How to resolve this problem  please?

Comment: you are using a bitwise operator on two strings - try casting them to `int` like so: `sbox[int(Plaintext[0], 16) ^ int(Key[0], 16)]`

Comment: Consider making your comment an answer, Kendas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bitwise exclusive or operator `^` works on integers. Seeing as you have hexadecimal representation of the strings, you just need to convert them (using the [`base`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) argument):

```
tempSbox = (sbox[int(Plaintext[0], 16) ^ int(Key[0], 16)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tempSbox = sbox[int(Plaintext[0],16) ^ int(Key[0],16)]
```

Comment: I thought about that, but I have an hexadecimal number: so when I put 
 int() I had this error:    invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'

Comment: @Guillaume - take a look at [kendas comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610782/how-to-resolve-this-error-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-long#comment74270442_43610782) you can do the conversion to base 16 too (the default is base 10 which is why you are seeing that error).

Comment: The point is not that list indices must be integers, but that the xor operator works with integers.